# Why don't the two ends both stay TIME_WAIT when closing a TCP connection

Tags: tcp

Normally, for closing  a TCP connection, client performs `active close` and stays TIME_WAIT. Server performs `passive close` and status changes from LAST_ACK to closed. Why doesn't server stay TIME_WAIT as well?Is it not necessary?

For example, if a new connection is built on the same address afterwards(the same source IP, source port, dst IP, dst port), will delayed packets confuse the server if it doesn't stay TIME_WAIT?

[image]

Comment: Because the end that first sends the close can't construct the new connection you describe because it is in TIME_WAIT. Of topic.

Comment: @EJP TIME_WAIT state can prevent the lost of last ACK by retransmiting it. What would happen if the retransmited ACKs are always lost?

Answer (score 1):

The point of TIME_WAIT is to ensure the sent ACK reaches the destination. The peer may choose to retransmit the FIN if the ACK got dropped. The TIME_WAIT state allows for that retransmission to be properly processed.

In the case of LAST_ACK, it is waiting for the ACK to the send FIN, and can retransmit the FIN if the ACK has not come. But, after the ACK arrives, there is nothing more to be done.

Now, suppose that the "server" (say S) is the one it TIME_WAIT, and the "client" (say C) was int LAST_ACK, but has now received the ACK sent by S. In theory, C could immediately reused the bound socket and issue another SYN immediately. What does the server do in that case?

Typically, the TCP stack will either drop or reject the connection attempt, because adding the new connection to its table will find an entry is already present. Some stacks can be configured to "fast recycle" sockets in TIME_WAIT. This means S replaces the existing TIME_WAIT entry with the new connection. The rationale for this is it indicates C has transitioned out of LAST_ACK. Whether or not the assumption is valid depends on whether or not NAT is being used, and how the NAT device is configured.